# Justifying the title of Shaw’s play “Arms and the Man”

Tags: title, george-bernard-shaw, arms-and-the-man

The title of Bernard Shaw’s *Arms and the Man* is a reference to Virgil’s work, but why the reference? What similarity do they have?

The title seems quite consistent if it is seen through the events of play: the play involves dialogues about wars, Raina’s father himself was a Major and her fiancé was an eminent soldier. So, that much accounts for the word “Arms” and as Bluntschli was the major cause of all upheavals caused in the house, so, maybe “the man” part would have been put for him. Is this explanation correct?

Comment: I think in Shaw's case it refers to 'man' in general rather than a particular man - the differing attitudes to war of Sergius and Bluntschli.